# AngularJS Directive jqLite convert .contents() to .children()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqlite

Consider this runnable example:

```js
var app=angular.module('myapp', [])
.directive('mydct', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    transclude:true,
    template:"<div>Template</div>",
    replace:true,
    scope:true,
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs,ctrl,transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn( function( clone, scope ) {
        console.log(clone[0]);
        console.log(clone[1]);
        console.log(clone[2]);
        console.log(clone[3]);
        //clone[3].attr('id');
      });
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='myapp'>
  <mydct>
    <div id='one'>This is one</div>
    <span id='two'>This is two</span>
  </mydct>
</body>
```

As you can see the clone parameter in the transcludeFunction will return the object as .contents(). This will include the text nodes. I have two questions:

1. Is there a way of converting this contents array to a children array, thus omitting text nodes?
2. As you can see, I will get out the text contents when accessing the elements in the array, what should I do to get them as elements, and be able to get the attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transcludeFn( function( clone, scope ) {
    var els, i;

    // convert to a normal array
    els = Array.prototype.slice.call(clone);

    // exclude text nodes
    els = els.filter(function (element) {
        return element.nodeType !== Node.TEXT_NODE;
    });

    // wrap each DOMElement in a jqLite object
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i] = angular.element(els[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        // do what you like with each clone's attribute
        console.log(els[i].attr('id'));
    }
});
```

This is a little verbose to emphasise the steps to go through, but feel free to simplify or shorten the code where necessary.

Comment: Oh dear, is it this complicated? Especially if you have to call angular.element each time you pick an element from a list?

Comment: the elements that you get in the `clone` array aren't jqLite/jQuery wrapped by default so if you want to use jqLite methods, then yes, you have to wrap them. Alternatively you can just use the native DOM API. For example `element.getAttribute('id')` to get the value of the id attribute.